# How can i make a page to be displayed after the user turns on the screen like the slidejoy app in flutter

Tags: flutter

How can i make a page to be displayed after the user turns on the screen and before he unclocks the screen likefir examble the user can swipe left to go to the unlock screen

Comment: Have a screen and make your Navigator open that screen when the user swipes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.